# Obfuscating ActionBarSherlock with Proguard

Tags: java, android, ant, proguard, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to obfuscate my android application using `proguard` and `ant` (`eclipse` + `proguard` never works, always fails with `error 1`). But I'm getting `class file ... unexpectedly contains class ...` warning all aver the place and the build fails. I also tried with `-ignorewarnings` option in `proguard`. The build suceeds but I get an unusable package.

Here's the ant output:

```
-post-compile:

optimize:
     [jar] Building jar: /home/binoy/git/Vibhinna/proguard/unoptimized.jar
     [java] ProGuard, version 4.8
     [java] Reading input...
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R$array.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R$array]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R$attr.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R$attr]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R$bool.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R$bool]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R$color.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R$color]
     ....
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R$xml.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R$xml]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/actionbarsherlock/R.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.actionbarsherlock.R].
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/DetailsDialogFragment$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.DetailsDialogFragment$1]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/DetailsDialogFragment.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.DetailsDialogFragment]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/HoloAlertDialogBuilder.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.HoloAlertDialogBuilder]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/MiscMethods.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.MiscMethods]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$1$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$1$1]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$1$2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$1$2]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$1]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$10.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$10]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$11.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$11]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$2]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$3.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$3]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$4.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$4]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$5.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$5]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$6.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$6]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$7.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$7]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/NewDialogFragment$8.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.NewDialogFragment$8]
     ....
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/Preferences.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.Preferences]
     [java] Warning: class [classes/com/vibhinna/binoy/ProcessManager.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.vibhinna.binoy.ProcessManager]
     [java] Warning: there were 89 classes in incorrectly named files.
     [java]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
     [java]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
     [java]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
     [java]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
     [java] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
     [java]     at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:133)
     [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:197)
     [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:79)
     [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:493)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html (See section about using proguard)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure your proguard config file has the [recommended exclusions](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html) for ActionbarSherlock:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; } 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Also try adding

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/aK3fLYg08Jw/hm5_srL1MP8J).

Comment: Still no change, 89 classes in incorrectly named files still.

Comment: Also try adding `-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;

}`

Comment: make sure you add unoptimized.jar as a library jar, if it is external to your project: `-libraryjars /home/binoy/git/Vibhinna/proguard/unoptimized.jar` to the config file

Comment: It's not a library jar, it's created by ant.

Answer (score 3):

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: class file ... unexpectedly contains class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)

You should specify the proper base directory in your input class path: "-injars ......**/classes**".